# How to calculate the derivative of the following integral $\int x_j^{\alpha}dj$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate some help to understand how to solve the following expression:
$$\frac{d}{dx_j} \biggl(\int x_j^{\alpha}dj\biggl)$$

At first I thought that the rule $\frac{d}{dx} \biggl(\int f(x)dx\biggl)=f(x)$ would hold in this case and the final answer would look like $\frac{d}{dx_j} \biggl(\int x_j^{\alpha}dj\biggl)=x_j^{\alpha}$. But apparently it doesn't hold. I honestly have no idea how to work with integrals like that. I don't even know if they have a special name and what mathematical concept I'm missing here.

Here is the answer according to my reference book: $\frac{d}{dx_j} \biggl(\int x_j^{\alpha}dj\biggl)=\alpha x_j^{\alpha-1}$ (more on that below).

---

#### **The original problem**

Find the first-order conditions for the following profit-maximization problem:

$$\max_{L_Y,x_j} L_Y^{1-\alpha} \int x_j^{\alpha}dj -wL_Y- \int p_jx_jdj $$

The first-order solutions to this problem are

$$w=(1-\alpha) \frac{Y}{L_Y}$$ and
$$p_j=\alpha L_Y^{1-\alpha}x_j^{\alpha-1}$$

*The original problem was taken from the third edition of the Introduction to Economic Growth by Charles I. Jones and Dietrich Vollrath, page 113, The Economics of the Romer Model chapter.*

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be a $dj$ in the integral $\int x_j^\alpha dj$ ?

Comment: Yes. You can see the exact page where I took this from here: [link](https://puu.sh/AsOv2/f417e532fc.png)